# Why I got "WARNING: Symbol name IF is a reserved name." in Arena Simulation?

Tags: arena-simulation

I have decide module  in the future connection i have Block A and Block B and they have capacity limit. I want to do a do a IF statment on first decide that IF any of block go to another decide module to give a chance percent %65 A %35 B. But if both block is full of capacity then In the first dice module they left from the system by dispose. I code in first module:
"IF (Block A.WIP < 475) AND (Block B.WIP < 475) == Decide 2 IF (Block A.WIP<475) AND (Block B.WIP >= 255) == Block A (Block A.WIP >= 475) AND (Block B.WIP < 255) == Block B
Else == Not parking due to park is full" and i got error that :"WARNING: Symbol name IF is a reserved name."